# Filling area with texture, cocos2d

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I've created dynamic terrain with Ray Wenderlich lesson, but I have some problem. I've used CCTexture2D for filling terrain area. At first minute it works totally ok, but after some time texture is gonna be smoother and smoother and smoother.
Here's the code:

Initialization of texture:

```
    ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE};

    [texturePattern.texture setTexParameters:&params];

    justTexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"text1.jpg"];
    [justTexture generateMipmap];
    [justTexture setTexParameters:&params];
```

Method draw where I fill my area:

-(void) draw
{

```
CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();

//ccGLBindTexture2D(texturePattern.texture.name);
ccGLBindTexture2D(justTexture.name);
ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords);

ccDrawColor4F(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillTexCoords);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHillVertices);

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _highVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _highTexCoords);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHighVertices);
```

}

Comment: which version of cocos2d-iphone?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, cocos2d is 2.0 version..